# Chinese font in pentaho report desginer ubuntu

Tags: fonts, pentaho, report-designer, chinese-locale

Hy all, I want to ask about chinese fonts in pentaho report designer

the scenario is like this :
first scenario :
 I use WenQuanYi Zen Hei font (a chinese font) in my report
-- when I print preview it works fine (the chinese character shows up)
-- when I print PDF it works too

the second scenario
I use Simsun font (a chinese font) in my report
-- when I print preview it works fine (the chinese character shows up)
-- when I print PDF it didnt work (the chinese character didnt show at all)

- fyi, I use ubuntu 10.04 and the WenQuan font its already in there meanwhile the simsun font is a font that I installed manually into my ubuntu OS

Can somebody help me?
Should I embed font into pentaho or something?

Answer (score 0):

How to enable RML Reports to be able to print chinese characters?

1. Make sure you have a chinese fonts (Simsun, Simhei, WenQuanYiZhenHei)
2. Embed your font into RML library and settings or we may say “register font that you want to use in RML”
3. Change the fontName in your RML Report (such as: slow_moving_report.rml)

LET’S GET STARTED :

In this case I want to use Simsun font in my Slow moving report

(FYI : I do this in Ubuntu 10.04)

How to have a chinese fonts?

You can installed manually or via terminal

•   If you want to install manually

1. Go to C:\WINDOWS\Fonts in your windows OS
2. Copy type font you want (.ttf / .ttc)
3. Copy to your Ubuntu OS
4. Double click on the font and install

•   If you want to install via terminal, you can refer to this link : http://xgwang.wordpress.com/2007/11/25/set-up-chinese-fonts-using-microsofts-simsunttf-in-ubuntu-71-gutsy/

After you have a chinese font in your OS, now we can register your font to report lab
Note : your report lab must be version 2.0 above
You can refer to this link : http://forum.openerp.com/forum/topic1943.html
But I do it in slightly different way

First, create a folder called “fonts” in this path /usr/lib/python2.6/dist_packages/reportlab/
And put SIMSUN.TTC in it

Note : the location where reportlab looking for TTF-files can be found here : rl_config.py
(you can search the file in your file system)

Second, after that go to /usr/share/pyshared/reportlab/lib/styles.py
And put this code below def  getSampleStyleSheet(): (this one id the original one)

def getSampleStyleSheet_JH():
    """Returns a chinese stylesheet object"""
    stylesheet = StyleSheet1()

```
stylesheet.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Normal',
                              fontName='Simsun',
                              fontSize=10,
                              leading=12)
               )

stylesheet.add(ParagraphStyle(name='BodyText',
                              parent=stylesheet['Normal'],
                              spaceBefore=6)
               )
stylesheet.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Italic',
                              parent=stylesheet['BodyText'],
                              fontName = 'Simsun-Italic')
               )

stylesheet.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Heading1',
                              parent=stylesheet['Normal'],
                              fontName = 'Simsun-Bold',
                              fontSize=18,
                              leading=22,
                              spaceAfter=6),
               alias='h1')

stylesheet.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Title',
                              parent=stylesheet['Normal'],
                              fontName = 'Simsun-Bold',
                              fontSize=18,
                              leading=22,
                              alignment=TA_CENTER,
                              spaceAfter=6),
               alias='title')

stylesheet.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Heading2',
                              parent=stylesheet['Normal'],
                              fontName = 'Simsun-Bold',
                              fontSize=14,
                              leading=18,
                              spaceBefore=12,
                              spaceAfter=6),
               alias='h2')

stylesheet.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Heading3',
                              parent=stylesheet['Normal'],
                              fontName = 'Simsun-BoldItalic',
                              fontSize=12,
                              leading=14,
                              spaceBefore=12,
                              spaceAfter=6),
               alias='h3')

stylesheet.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Bullet',
                              parent=stylesheet['Normal'],
                              firstLineIndent=0,
                              spaceBefore=3),
               alias='bu')

stylesheet.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Definition',
                              parent=stylesheet['Normal'],
                              firstLineIndent=0,
                              leftIndent=36,
                              bulletIndent=0,
                              spaceBefore=6,
                              bulletFontName='BoldItalic'),
               alias='df')

stylesheet.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Code',
                              parent=stylesheet['Normal'],
                              fontName='Courier',
                              fontSize=8,
                              leading=8.8,
                              firstLineIndent=0,
                              leftIndent=36))
```

Third, go to /opt/openerp61/server/openerp/report/render/rml2pdf/**init**.py
And change into this :

from trml2pdf import parseString, parseNode

from reportlab.lib.fonts import addMapping

from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics

from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

from reportlab.pdfbase.cidfonts import UnicodeCIDFont, findCMapFile

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('SimSun','SIMSUN.TTC'))  # the font name you put here must exactly the same with the one you copy in “fonts” folder in step 1

for facename in ['SimSun']:

addMapping(facename, 0, 0, facename)    #normal

addMapping(facename, 0, 1, facename)    #italic

addMapping(facename, 1, 0, facename)    #bold

addMapping(facename, 1, 1, facename)    #italic and bold

Forth, go to /opt/openerp61/server/openerp/report/render/rml2pdf/trml2pdf.py

•   Change your encoding from “cp1252” to “UTF-8”
•   Add following code:

from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_LEFT, TA_RIGHT, TA_CENTER, TA_JUSTIFY
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet_JH, ParagraphStyle, StyleSheet1

•   Replace all “getSampleStyleSheet” to “getSampleStyleSheet_JH”

Last step restart your openerp service TWICE
Note : if when you restart your opener service, it prompt out  “start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 5445: No such process”, you can commented the code in step 3 and find out what the error and uncommented again but don’t forget to restart your service again